# "Not a function" error when using criteria builder lower

Tags: jpa, groovy, micronaut

I'm implementing Query Specifications in my Micronaut (3.7 & groovy) app but I have an issue when I want to query by a case insensitive field.

This is the specification that I have (I have omitted certain imports to reduce code length):

```
import io.micronaut.data.repository.jpa.criteria.PredicateSpecification

class ProductSpecifications {

    static PredicateSpecification<ProductEntity> containsName(String name) {
        return (root, cb) -> cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("name")), name.toLowerCase())
    }
    static PredicateSpecification<ProductEntity> createQueryBySpecifications(ProductParams params) {

        PredicateSpecification<ProductEntity> query = PredicateSpecification.ALL as PredicateSpecification<ProductEntity>

        if (params.name) {
            query = query & containsName(params.name)
        }

        return query
    }
}
```

And I get the following error `cb.lower()`, without it I have no issue:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/products?name=novo",
            "templated": false
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Internal Server Error: Not supported operation!"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have also tried using: `cb.function("LOWER", String.class, root.get("name"))` but it produces the same error.

I am fairly new to Micronaut but am I missing something? I feel like this should not give me an issue since it's the same concept as Spring Data and I had no issues with it in Spring Data in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on the same issue.

### Problem

Problem #1: `CriteriaBuilder` doesn't cover `ilike` (case-insensitive `LIKE`) operator. It only provides `like` operator and `lower` function.

Problem #2: Micronaut's implementation in `AbstractCriteriaBuilder.lower()` is `throw notSupportedOperation()`, so `cb.lower()` is of no use.

### Solution

Micronaut passes its `RuntimeCriteriaBuilder` as the implementation of `CrtieriaBuilder` to the `PredicateSpecification`.

`RuntimeCriteriaBuilder` in particular implements `PersistentEntityCriteriaBuilder` containing factory methods for operators not available in `CriteriaBuilder`.

One of them is `ilikeString(Expression<String> x, Expression<String> y)` which can be used.

### Example

Overall, this predicate specification works in my tests:

```kotlin
fun ownerNameContains(text: String?) =
    PredicateSpecification<Pet> { root, criteriaBuilder ->
        if (text == null) null
        else {
            val owner = root.join<Pet, Owner>("owner", JoinType.LEFT)
            (criteriaBuilder as PersistentEntityCriteriaBuilder).ilikeString(
                owner[Owner::name],
                LiteralExpression("%${text}%")
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using non JPA persistence: Micronaut Data JDBC / R2DBC / MongoDB, which has the criteria builder that doesn’t implement all the possible methods.